# O que acontece quanto atribuímos o valor default a objetos?

Tags: c#, tipagem, inicialização

Exemplo:

```
public Carro Metodo(string marca) {

 Carro carro = default;

 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(marca))
 {
   carro.Marca = marca
 }

 return carro;
}
```

Estudando na internet, percebi que alguns objetos eram inicializados com `default`.

O que acontece quando fazemos isso?

Comment: [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default) de referência.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como o próprio nome diz é atribuído um valor padrão daquele tipo para a variável. Isto pode variar mas em geral é um valor equivalente a um zero, uma inicialização simples.

Em tipos por valor seria o valor mínimo, que costuma ser o 0, mas nem sempre, um `DateTime` por exemplo não é bem um 0 porque este número nem existe neste tipo (começa no dia 1 do mês 1 e ano 1).

Tipos por referência costumavam ser o seu padrão como um `null` porque este é o endereço 0 e indica que não tem um objeto ali. Isto é um problema no C# 8 porque ele passou a não reconhecer como anuláveis os tipos por referência como era antes (ainda é possível configurar isto por projeto, arquivo ou trecho de código), então usar o `default` não é adequado porque ele gerará um nulo que não pode ser usado para este tipo. Não dará erro, mas produzirá um *warning*, então o que ocorrerá aí depende da versão do C# e de como o trecho esteja configurado, ou se o tipo for declarado explicitamente como anulável (`Carro?` por exemplo).

Todo programador de primeira classe que *warning* é erro em qualquer código que não seja um protótipo.

Então **o `default` não deve ser abusado**, geralmente o valor padrão é óbvio e é raro você querer explicitamente o valor padrão, pelo menos quando sabe o tipo. Em tipos por referência geralmente você não quer o valor padrão que é nulo, isto induz a erro e é melhor inicializar o objeto com seu construtor.

Se um tipo não tem um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) provavelmente ele foi conceituado de forma equivocada. Parece ser o caso deste tipo `Carro`, partindo do princípio que `Carro` é um tipo por referência. O ideal é que tenha um construtor que produza um objeto válido e não use o `default` onde não precisa.

Na verdade o `default` existe principalmente para os casos onde você não conhece o tipo de antemão e por isto não sabe qual é o valor padrão dele. Isto ocorre em programação genérica (eventualmente com reflexão também). O abuso dele leva a consequências não previstas ou erradas, como parece ser o caso deste código, ainda que o problema maior é a falta de construtor e/ou inicialização dos seus membros.

Veja este código (que só exemplifica o uso, não é bom fazer nada disto):

```
using static System.Console;
#nullable enable //o .NET Fiddle não liga o anulável por padrão

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Carro carro = default;
        WriteLine(carro.Marca);
        Carro? carro2 = default;
        WriteLine(carro2.Marca);
        Carro carro3 = new Carro();
        WriteLine(carro3.Marca);
    }
}

public class Carro {
    public string Marca;
    public string Modelo = "";
    public string? Tipo;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SvQ1aT). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/DefaultValue.cs). Ainda outros locais não possuem C# 8.

Note os *warnings*, eles deveriam ser resolvidos, isto é programação moderna, e vai te beneficiar

Eu entendo os motivos de terem feito assim, mas foi um erro terem escolhido essa semântica para tipos por referência. O ideal é que fosse chamado o construtor padrão quando usa o `default`, a não ser para tipos anuláveis.

Answer (score 7):

A sua variável passa a apontar para o valor padrão de variáveis do tipo objeto (null).

O default existe por 2 motivos:

- Para deixar a sua intenção mais fácil de entender para quem está lendo o seu código.
- Para que você não precise procurar na documentação, qual o valor padrão de cada tipo de variável, quando você quiser 'reseta-la' para o valor inicial (null para objetos, 0 para ints, etc...).